# Interesting insights from the site analytics available to users with 25K

Tags: discussion

Access/views into the [site analytics are available to users with 25,000 reputation](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)

By my count we have 39 users with this privilege (plus moderators).

Has anyone done any analysis on the raw data that might be interesting to the rest of us?

Comment: One thing those analytics do show is *something* happened around the 28th or 29th of July and we've been p̶a̶y̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ benefiting from it a lot since.  I'll be damned if I know what that was though... ;)

Comment: [Wil Wheaton's birthday!](https://dontbeadickday.com/)

Comment: @bertieb Hmmm, that must be what it is. I wonder if there's any other interesting correlation between site visits and celebrity birthdays.

Comment: Mods get the privilege as well, but we already had access to the data before.

Comment: @Mokubai I'd love to believe WW is a SU-er (he was a /.-er back in the day), but I fear the possibility is remote. I'd happily check for those correlation but I'm a ways off 25k yet...

Comment: @NormalHuman Please don't abuse your privileges. "Since this is a restricted privilege, ***we'd prefer you not share the raw data.** However, we do hope you will share your analysis of the data with other users on meta. "

Comment: @DavidPostill – what do you think is the valid point with hiding that data?

Comment: @miroxlav You will have to ask SE. They are the ones who asked us not to share it.